# Developing code in Visual studio that also runs in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, portability

I have developed Visual C++ 2008 code that runs in Windows.  I have made it cross platform also so that it runs under Linux.

I am greatly concerned about distributing source code and even just libraries that Linux users can link to.

I have used CMake and Code::Blocks (only in Linux) but it was still developed using Visual Studio 2008 for most development.

The license looked similar for the professional version and the express version.  Let me know if binaries can be released to run under Linux and also if it is okay to open source the entire project.  I am pretty far into this project.  Maybe it should have been done entirely in Linux.

I am also interested to jump to another Windows compiler such as MinGW in addition because of the Visual Studio licensing restrictions.  Is this the path that cross platform programs are usually created or can they be created primarily with the professional or express Visual Studio compilers?

Comment: I am worried about "distribute Distributable Code to run on a platform other than Microsoft operating systems, run-time technologies or application platforms;" This could force creation of libraries and never allow a full open source project. I am also interested in proprietary code both open and closed source projects.

Comment: You are asking for legal advice and I am not a lawyer.  My understanding is that you can distribute your own source code as you wish.  Source code you did not write is copyrighted by its author.

Comment: The source code does all belong to me.